# add only one property from each item to listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a List in ASP.NET with users in chatroom. each user has a connectionid and a nick. After a new user has been added, I want to write nick of each user into the ListBox1. How can I do it? Thank you.

[image]

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
class User
{
    public string connectionid { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    users.Add(new User { connectionid = TextBox1.Text, nick = TextBox2.Text });
    //I want to populate ListBox1 with nick for each user
}
```

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I would suspect the downvotes are due to pretty much everybody on this site disliking screenshots of IDEs instead of code. Just a hunch.

Comment: @ethorn10 I included the code as well.

Comment: @user3071591 I find it ironic that you want people to explain downvotes when you can only seem to respond to answers (and suggestions) with "didn't work".  Can to elaborate on what didn't work?

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint and do some general debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt at @SLaks suggestion was close, but you can't add the list of users to the listbox in that manner. This should get you closer:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    users.Add(new User { connectionid = TextBox1.Text, nick = TextBox2.Text });
    foreach (User u in users) {
        lbUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(u.nick, u.connectionid));
    }
}
```

To `Add` to the `Items` collection of a `ListBox` requires the item to be a `ListItem`. You can instantiate a new one inline and pass the string/value pair that you want associated with it.